# Jquery hide some tds based on class

Tags: jquery

I would like to know if it's possible to hide tds based on class. let's say I have this table:

```
<table id="newspaper-a">
    <tr>
       <td class="1">1</td>
       <td class="2">1</td>
       <td class="3">1</td>
       <td class="4">1</td>
       <td class="5">1</td>
       <td class="td1">1</td>
       <td class="td2">2</td>
       <td class="td3">3</td>
       <td class="td4">4</td>
       <td class="td5">5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to hide all tds with class="tdx", how can I achieve this using JQuery when the page is loaded?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RGjhG/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$('#newspaper-a td[class^=td]').hide()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/38zhW/)

*Note: it has a drawback, if you add another class to the `td` like `<td class="some td5">5</td>`, this will fail*

A different approach without any third party plugins

```
$('#newspaper-a td').filter(function(idx, el){
    var classes = (this.className || '').split(' ');
    var filter = false, regex = /^td\d+$/;
    $.each(classes, function(idx, value){
        if(regex.test(value)){
            filter = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return filter;
}).hide();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/P8yRk/)

Comment: Then you could use: $('td[class*=td]');
But this would depend on other classes that could be applied, as you pointed out.

Comment: Yes, it is dependent on new class names not conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
$('td[class^="td"]').hide();
```

Use `td` selector and `class` it will hide all the td with class td1,td2,etc..